# Odd Dynamic SQL Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

All, I have the following dynamic SQL Query

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255);
SET @TableName = 'BadCodesErrSumm';
DECLARE @DropSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DropSql = 
    'IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
                FROM Report.sys.objects 
                WHERE name = ''' + @TableName + ''' AND type = ''U'') 
     DROP TABLE [IPAReport]..[' + @TableName + '];'
PRINT @DropSql;
EXEC @DropSql;
```

This produces the following error

```
Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
The name 'IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
                FROM Report.sys.objects 
                WHERE name = 'BadCodesErrSumm' AND type = 'U') 
          DROP TABLE [Report]..[BadCodesErrSumm];' is not a valid identifier.
```

However, the printed output

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
           FROM Report.sys.objects 
           WHERE name = 'BadCodesErrSumm' AND type = 'U') 
DROP TABLE [Report]..[BadCodesErrSumm];
```

executes fine. **What am I missing?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Never use `[' + @TableName + ']`. Always use `quotename(@TableName, '[')`.

Comment: I am always lazy here as it is for a fairly specialized WinForms app. I am certian that there will be no danger of injection attacks but I suppose I should always do this as best practice. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: and Why not just `Select OBJECT_ID From Sys.tables Where name = 'Your Table Name'`
and Why `Select OBJECT_ID From IPAReport.tables Where name = 'Your Table Name'`. Sorry I could not understand the meaning of `IPAReport` ?

Comment: I am not connected to the `Report` (formally `IPAReport`) database. This is why I have to use this notation. I cannot use a `USE` statement to switch as this invoked from C# as part of a batch...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
EXEC sp_executesql @DropSql;
```

Or

```
EXEC(@DropSql);
```

That said, a couple of suggestions:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255);

SET @TableName = N'BadCodesErrSumm';      -- always use N prefix on Unicode strings

DECLARE @DropSql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DropSql = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1      -- again, N prefix
                FROM IPAReport.sys.tables -- use sys.tables to avoid 'U' check
                WHERE name = @TableName)  -- use a proper parameter
     DROP TABLE [IPAReport]..' 
       + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ';'      -- QUOTENAME is safer as @GSerg pointed out

PRINT @DropSql;

EXEC sp_executesql @DropSql, N'@TableName NVARCHAR(255)', @TableName;
```

Comment: So here on the line '-- use a proper parameter' what would the parameter be defined as?

Comment: @Killercam it's defined on the very last line of the script, as part of the second argument to sp_executesql.